# `_naked`: Trying to compile legacy 8051 (FX2) code with SDCC, newer version stumbles

Tags: compatibility, 8051, sdcc

I have legacy code for an embedded 8051 core (in a cypress FX2) that *used* to compile with other versions of SDCC. However, current SDCC doesn't know the `_naked` qualifier:

```
delay.c:27: syntax error: token -> '_naked' ; column 21
```

as triggered by

```
static void
udelay1 (void) _naked
{
  _asm              ; lcall that got us here took 4 bus cycles
    ret         ; 4 bus cycles
  _endasm;
}
```

and other occurrences.

As `_naked` practically is supposed to tell the C compiler to "nah, ignore the fact that you're a C compiler and understand that you'd need to save frame context", I don't feel like I should just `#define` it away.

Is there any solution to this? Should I just go ahead and manually inline the assembler wherever a `_naked` function is used? I feel like I'd betraying the compiler on a `CALL` there, and that would change the timing.

Comment: The downvote more than a year after posting and answering this question is democratically very fine, but I'd still like to know what I could've done better, so I'd love to read a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_naked` was replaced by `__naked` in newer versions of SDCC. Same applies to `asm`/`__asm`, `at`/`__at`, `interrupt`,`bit`,`xdata`/`__…`.

So, this turned out to be an exercise in regex replacements.

I'm still having linker/ranlib/mostly `ar` problems, and CMake ignores what I instruct it to use as compilers, but oh well.